# Java: 4 bytes to 32 bit integer

Tags: java, integer, byte, unsigned, signed

Im trying to understand the following piece of code:

```
int omgezetteTijd =
((0xFF & rekenOmNaarTijdArray[0]) << 24) | ((0xFF & rekenOmNaarTijdArray[1]) << 16) |((0xFF & rekenOmNaarTijdArray[2]) << 8) | (0xFF & rekenOmNaarTijdArray[3]);
```

What I do not understand is why do you AND it with OxFF, you're ANDING an 8 bit value with 8 bits like so (11111111), so this should give you the same result.

But, when I do not AND it with OxFF I'm getting negative values? Cant figure out why this is happening?

Comment: Why do you repliate the job of what a `ByteBuffer` can do for you?

Comment: Because I want to understand different data type's and know how to use them :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you *or* a byte with an int the byte will be promoted to an int. By default this is done with [sign extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension). In other words:

```
                           //                      sign bit
                           //                         v
byte b = -1;               //                         11111111 = -1
int i = (int) b;           // 11111111111111111111111111111111 = -1
                           // \______________________/
                           //      sign extension
```

By doing `& 0xFF` you prevent this. I.e.

```
                           //                      sign bit
                           //                         v
byte b = -1;               //                         11111111 = -1
int i = (int) (0xFF & b);  // 00000000000000000000000011111111 = 255
                           // \______________________/
                           //     no sign extension
```

Answer (score 3):

0xFF as a `byte` represents the number -1.  When it's converted to an `int`, it is still -1, but that has the bit representation `0xFFFFFFFF`, because of sign extension.  `& 0xFF` avoids this, treating the byte as unsigned when converting to an int.